# unable to link resource with controller class by using PathVariable technique in spring mvc

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

### this is my index page:

> ```
> <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
> <h1>Employee List</h1>
> <table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">
> <tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th>
> <th>City</th><th>Cars</th></tr>
> <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">
> <tr>
> <td>${emp.name }</td>
> <td>${emp.address }</td>
> <td>${emp.city }</td>
> <td>${emp.cars}</td>
> <td><a href="editemp/${emp.name }">Edit</a>
> <td><a href="deleteemp/${emp.name }">Delete</a>
> </tr></c:forEach>
> </table>
> <a href="empform">Add New Employee</a>"
> ```

problem is when i click on other link than it works fine but when i click on editemp or deleteemp link,than it shows me error:The requested resource is not available

### This is my controller class:

> ```
> package first;
>
> import java.util.List;
>
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
> import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
>
> @Controller
> public class EmpController {
>   @Autowired
>   EmployeeDao dao; 
>
> @RequestMapping("/empform")
> public ModelAndView showForm()
> {
>   return new ModelAndView("empform","command",new Employee());
> }
> @RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
> public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("emp") Employee employee)
> {
>   dao.saveEmployee(employee);
>   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewemp");
> }
> @RequestMapping("/viewemp")
> public ModelAndView viewemp()
> {
>   List<Employee> list=dao.getAllEmployee();
>   return new ModelAndView("viewemp","list",list);
> }
>
> @RequestMapping(value="/editemp/{name}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
> public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable String name)
> {
>   Employee e=dao.getbyName(name);
>   return new ModelAndView("empeditform","command",e);
> }
>
> @RequestMapping(value="/saveedit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
> public ModelAndView saveedit(@ModelAttribute("emp")Employee employee)
> {
>   dao.updateEmployee(employee);
>   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewemp");
> }
>
> @RequestMapping(value="/deleteemp/{name}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
> public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable String name)
> {
>   dao.delete(name);
>   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewemp");
> }
> }
> ```

Please tell me,why it is unable to map with controller method specified in controller class.....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try for your links to to update them to use the context path:

```
<td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editemp/${emp.name}">Edit</a>
<td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteemp/${emp.name}">Delete</a>
```

This post has a few other ways that you can specify your routes in a jsp page:
[[How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name][1])

Also, for the controller routes to be registered, you will need to set component scan to look for any annotations:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="namespace to controller class" />
```