# Java Spring Framework-Bootstrap Integration

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

I just started learning spring framework.
I have met a problem and decided to share it to help you.
First I added the project bootstrap library for a project.
Then I downloaded a free template from the Internet. I put the resources of this template in the project in the following location (see WebContent / WEB-INF / view / resources)

```html
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>SB Admin - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
  <link href="${contextPath}/WebContent/WEB-INF/view/resources/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="${contextPath}/WebContent/WEB-INF/view/resources/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="${contextPath}/WebContent/WEB-INF/view/resources/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Then I copied the codes of the login page from the source code into the project and defined the locations of the files used for `HTML` at the top.(you can see codes below)

When I compile and run my code, I do not have libraries added and I see a page with simple `HTML` code. What is wrong with me? How can I fix this problem? If you tell me my mistakes and you help me, I'm happy. Everyone thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing `${contextPath}/WebContent/WEB-INF/......` to `${contextPath}/......`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I still have a simple html code without resources. Is there another way?

Comment: did you add the 'view' in the path? Like `${contextPath}/view/resources/........`

Comment: yes I add the ‘view’ this -> link=href=“${contextPath}/view/resources/.... but it didn’t work

Comment: What does ´${contextPath}´ results in the html code? Inspect it and see

Comment: @JorgeCampos I see result in html code my project name: “Lomis”

Comment: And also see this thread. I think your question is really a duplicate of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. First, in my project "application-context.xml" 
I added the following code to the page. I moved my template files to "/ WebContent / resources / thema /" :

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/thema/"  
cache-period="31556926"/
```

I defined contextPath :

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

Don't forget to define this library for this :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

After, I changed the path to the template folder in my .jsp file as follows:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>SB Admin - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
<link href="${contextPath}/resources/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
<link href="${contextPath}/resources/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Custom styles for this template-->
<link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

This solved my problem.

I got help here for the solution:

[Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)

and

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Thank you for your good help :  [Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos)