# HTML5 <base> Tag with root relative url

Tags: html, base-tag

Please help me understand the functionality of the `<base>` tag's href attribute.

I have a website hosted at `http://goodsite.org/bob`. other sites are hosted at `http://goodsite.org/others`.

I am planning to move my application to `http://bettersite.org/bob`.

In order to support this I have a base url in my header.
    `<base href="/bob/">`.

My links look something like this: `<a href="thatonething.img">That one thing</a>`

As hoped I am seeing the links as expected (e.g. `"http://goodsite.org/bob/thatonething.img"`)

Question:

**Does `<base>` tag universally support root relative urls (i.e. `href="/bob/"`)?**

This seems to work in my testing but I am having a little more trouble reading through the specifications. More generally I'm wanting to know if I am misusing this tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/what-are-the-recommendations-for-html-base-tag?rq=1

Comment: @LGSon, not a duplicate.  I posted after reading that question because it is lacking information (even in all the answers) relating to the use of root relative (path-absolute) urls

Comment: Well, if you search for _root_ you'll find a few comments, still, this one is clarify that, and is a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @LGSon, thank you very much for looking at this. The link you provided does touch on this in a couple answers.  Having already read that answer I created this question.  I do know that this can work as evidenced by my question.  What I'm really hoping to do is build consensus that this is actually a proper way to use base tag (i.e. is to spec).  I did try to decipher the specifications around <base> tag but it proved to difficult for me to decipher.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Does `<base>` tag universally support root relative urls (i.e. `href="/bob/"`)?**

Yes, `<base>` accepts domain-relative (path-absolute) URLs and will correctly resolve them relative to the host name.

`<base href="/bob/">` means that you want all path-relative URLs (i.e. URLs that contain just a path but *don't* start with `/`) to be relative to `/bob/`, such that

- `<a href="foo.html">` will point to `/bob/foo.html`, regardless of the domain.

Domain-absolute and path-absolute links will not be adjusted: respectively,

- `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">` will still point to `https://stackoverflow.com`, and
- `<a href="/bar">` will still point to `/bar`.

As long as this is how you intend for your path-relative links to behave, you're not misusing the `<base>` element this way. As always, when using the `<base>` element it's a good idea to test your links from time to time to make sure they're still pointing to the right URLs.