# Spring Boot serves static content with wrong URL

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm developing an application using Spring Boot and while in IDEA with an Application configuration all works fine, if I try deploying it on a web server which define a different context from "/", all my resources aren't loaded because of URL mismatch.

For example, my test tomcat define the context "localhost:8080/myApp" but the application look for resources at "localhost:8080" instead.

I tried to set the option `server.servlet.context-path=/myApp` in my application.properties but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you deploy it on an existing Tomcat or are you using the embedded Spring Boot Tomcat?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle On an existing tomcat on which I have no control over configurations.

Comment: The problem is your pages, whichm probably, have a src url of `/static/images` which will load them from the root. You will need to prefix it with the context root (or if you are using something like thymeleaf use `th:src` instead. The `server.*` properties don't have any effect when deploying the application to an external tomcat as those are only for controlling the embedded tomcat instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah, the problem is definitly that, but I was wandering if there was a way to define the application context at build time, so it doesn't have to be defined in the code. At the moment I have solved it doing as you said, but I don't like it too much.
Thank you for the `server.*` properties clarification, didn't know that!

Comment: Why would it need to be defined. THat is what the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is for (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name). But as stated you would probably be better of ditching JSP and use Thymeleaf and then use `th:src` which will do it automatically for you.