# How to uri encode a string in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

if I have a string "output" that equals a url:

```
${output} = "/testing/method/thing.do?foo=testing&bar=foo"
```

**in the jsp,** how would I convert that string into:

```
%2Ftesting%2Fmethod%2Fthing.do%3Ffoo%3Dtesting%26bar%3Dfoo
```

using

```
<c:out value="${output}"/>
```

?
I need to URLEncoder.encode(url) in the c:out somehow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not directly possible with standard JSTL tags/functions. Here's a hack with help of `<c:url>`:

```
<c:url var="url" value=""><c:param name="output" value="${output}" /></c:url>
<c:set var="url" value="${fn:substringAfter(url, '=')}" />
<p>URL-encoded component: ${url}</p>
```

If you want to do it more cleanly, create an EL function. At the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995) you can find a basic kickoff example. You'd like to end up as:

```
<p>URL-encoded component: ${my:urlEncode(output, 'UTF-8')}</p>
```

with

```
public static String urlEncode(String value, String charset) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return URLEncoder.encode(value, charset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<c:out value="${output}" escapeXml="true" />
```

Granted, this will only escape special characters from XML.

Comment: looking for something that actually does a uri encode right there in c:out.. any ideas?