# Is it possible to component encode a URL with a # anchor in it using h:outputLink?

Tags: java, url, jsf, url-encoding

I have a URL that looks like 

`http://server/context/page.jsf?param1=value1#state=statename::stateparam=value2`

Is there anyway to the take this URL and encode the components (the two values) using `h:outputLink`?

I've tried

```
<h:outputLink value="page.jsf">
    <f:param name="param1" value="#{servervalue1}#state=statename::stateparam=#{servervalue2}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{linkname}"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

But it encodes the the state section of the URL so it no longer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. Best what you can do is to create a custom EL function which invokes `URLEncoder#encode()` like follows:

```
public static String urlEncode(String value) {
    return URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
<h:outputLink value="page.jsf?param1=#{util:urlEncode(value1)}#state=statename::stateparam=#{util:urlEncode(value2)}">
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no built in JSTL function to encoding URLs?

Comment: No, I would otherwise have suggested this :) There's however an ugly hack/workaround possible, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952659/how-to-uri-encode-a-string-in-jsp/4952889#4952889).