# How would you get a returned value from a JSTL tag back into an EL statement?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, casting

Basically I have a custom tag that handles querying a java object for me.

```
<c:set var="profit">
    <ct:get-profit transaction="${transaction}"/>
</c:set>
```

Now the problem is that I want to use that value (which is a float in an if statement, which I do as so:

```
 <c:when test="${profit > 0}">
```

When I do that though I end up getting the following error.

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert -141.75 of type class java.lang.String to class       java.lang.Long
```

I have no idea how I can make this work. I was under the impression that JSTL's would handle casting for you, is that incorrect? Either way, how would you go about making this work? Thanks

Comment: Any idea why I would get an error such as this then?

Comment: I believe it's because of decimal points. I am not sure though why it is trying to cast Long.

Comment: A good read on JSTL auto casting here .. http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/10/07/jstl1.html

Comment: Can you try doing 0.00 instead of 0? <c:when test="${profit > 0.00}">

Comment: Yup cool beans, I figured that out on my own and it worked for me. If you write up a simple answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Weird I guess but it worked out well enough.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of any help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing `0.00` instead of `0`? `<c:when test="${profit > 0.00}">` .

The reason you have to it is because 0 is getting treated as Long by the EL parser. However, "0.00" is getting treated as a float.

Answer (score 1):

Everything which you set in the **body** of `<c:set>` is implicitly converted to `String` by `Object#toString()`. You'd like to use its `value` attribute instead which keeps the type unchanged.

I'd suggest to replace the `<ct:get-profit>` tag by an EL function. Since this tag doesn't seem to render any markup, you could do it as good (and better) with an EL function.

```
<c:set var="profit" value="${ct:getProfit(transaction)}" />
```

in combination with

```
public static float getProfit(Transaction transaction) {
    // Implement.
}
```

For a more detailed example how to configure such a function, check the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995).