# tomcat with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

How can i compile and run jsp pages using tomcat. Where should i place my jsp page. In which folder i have to placed it.

Comment: Like this: http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/servlet_com/deployingJSPtoTomCat.html

Comment: Well I am using netbeans IDE and it does everything for me. What IDE are you using?

Comment: how can i run jsp page with help of tomcat???

Comment: which v link i have to click inorder to accept an answer???

Comment: This basic [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/user/camigonz#p/u/0/0Xqm131EG6Y) might be useful for you if you just want to learn how to write a **very basic** jsp example and run it on Tomcat

Answer (score 5):

A simple example of JSP can be like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<% out.println("Hello World"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

---

To run this JSP page
Save the file in `c:\Program Files\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\jsp-examples\` as `HelloWorld.jsp`
Start the TomCat Server.
Type the following `URL` in the address bar of your web browser.
`http://localhost:8080/jsp-examples/helloworld.jsp`
The JSP page will be displayed in the web browser.

---

A JSP page is converted to a servlet internally by the JSP Engine.And the source file for that servlet can be found at `\work` directory in TomCat.

---

For more information on how JSP works and how it is different from Servlet take a look at this

[What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)

Also Take a look at
[Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)