# Display forwarded JSP with url-pattern "/*"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, front-controller

To improve my java skills, I'm trying to build a simple j2ee framework (MVC).

I built it to handle every request in a FrontServlet. Here is the mapping that I used :

```
web.xml :
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Front</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.FrontServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Front</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*My problem is that when I forward the request from the FrontServlet to a JSP, obviously, the JSP request is handle by the FrontServlet and the view isn't rendered.*

- **How can I resolve this problem by keeping the url-pattern "/*" ?**
- **Is there a way to render a JSP in a Servlet without performance losses ?**

Thanks in advance for your reply !

---

- Solution 1 (@Bryan Kyle)

I'm trying to follow your advise. I created this filter :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
   ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
   throws IOException, ServletException 

   {
       HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

       if(!req.getRequestURL().toString().endsWith("jsp"))
       {
           // I changed the servlet url-pattern to "/front.controller"
           req.getRequestDispatcher("/front.controller").forward(req, response);
           /*chain.doFilter(req, resp);*/
       }
   }
```

---

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>test.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

- **Is it right?**

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Filter` is an inappropriate solution for a front controller approach.

You want to refine the `url-pattern` of your servlet so that it matches e.g. `/pages/*` or `*.do`. You don't want your front controller to kick in on irrelevant requests like CSS/JS/images/etc. To take `/pages/*` as an example, assuming that you've a JSP in `/WEB-INF/foo.jsp`, then the following in a servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo() + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

should display the JSP in question on http://localhost:8080/contextname/pages/foo.

#### See also:

- [Design patterns in Java web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Yes, it's probably the easiest way to resolve the problem, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here might be that you're using a `Servlet` instead of a `ServletFilter`.

A ServletFilter, as the name suggests filters requests by providing pre- and post-processing on the request.  You'd probably want to use a Filter if you needed to do something like the following:

- Provide security checks across an entire application
- Set request properties that are picked up by a servlet or jsp
- Compress a response
- Log timing information
- Etc.

Have a look at the documentation about [Servlet Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).

Comment: It could be a solution. I will try and I will edit my question