# How to set value of html text field using java code

Tags: java, html, servlets

I can get the value of a textfield from html to java using the following code:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

Is there a way where I can set an HTML text field using a Java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just let JSP/EL print it in the `value` attribute of the field.

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="${param.id}" />
```

or, better, to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html), use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html).

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.id)}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)