# JSP: some form fields are stable and others are not!

Tags: java, jsp

I want to enable the input field when check box is checked. Also, I want to make a server side validation of the text field, to be filled, if the check box is selected, the **problem** I face is that when I make check for more than one and submit the form with empty values of the filed then make validation in the servlet and return the result to the user to fill the inputs, one of the check fields is checked and the other is not, even I use `param`  for filed stability for both, I don't know what is the reason!

Here's the HTML code

```
 <div class="groupElement">

  <input type="checkbox" name="communicationWay" id="communicationWay2" value="emailOption" ${param.communicationWay == 'emailOption'?'checked':'' } onchange="chgtx('email','communicationWay2')"/>
  <label>Email</label>


     <input class="inpClass" id="email" type="text" name="emailComm" value="${param.emailComm}" disabled/>

</div>

 <div class="groupElement">

  <input type ="checkbox" name="communicationWay" id="communicationWay"  value="cellPhoneOption" ${param.communicationWay == 'cellPhoneOption'?'checked':''} onchange="chgtx('cellPhone','communicationWay')" />
   <label> Cell phone number</label>

    <input class="inpClass" id="cellPhone" type ="text" name="cellPhoneNoComm" value="${param.cellPhoneNoComm}" disabled />

     </div>
```

and here's the java script function that trigger between enabling and disabling the input fields

```
 function chgtx(field, checkbox) {

            var myField = document.getElementById(field);
            var checkBtton = document.getElementById(checkbox);
            myField.disabled= !checkBtton.checked;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkbox elements have the same name. So in the server side you have to use `request.getParameterValues()` to get all checked values.

```
String[] communicationWays = request.getParameterValues("communicationWay");
// ...
```

When you use `request.getParameter()`, such as `${param}` is doing, only one value will be returned, which is the first one of the group. You can use `${paramValues}` to get all values in EL.

However, using `${paramValues}` in EL to set the `checked` state isn't exactly trivial. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Create a custom EL function which does something like

   ```
   ${util:contains(paramValues.communicationWays, 'emailOption') ? 'checked' : ''}
   ${util:contains(paramValues.communicationWays, 'phoneOption') ? 'checked' : ''}
   ```

   with a

   ```
   public static boolean contains(Object[] array, Object value) {
       Arrays.sort(array);
       return Arrays.binarySearch(array, value) > -1;
   }
   ```
2. Create a `Map<String, Boolean>` in servlet and use it instead in EL.

   ```
   Map<String, Boolean> communicationWays = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
   request.setAttribute("communicationWays", communicationWays);

   for (String communicationWay : request.getParameterValues("communicationWay")) {
       communicationWays.put(communicationWay, true);
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   ${communicationWays.emailOption ? 'checked' : ''}
   ${communicationWays.phoneOption ? 'checked' : ''}
   ```

Comment: @BlausC, I make the second option and it works, many thanx. But about the first way, where should I define the contains method?

Comment: An example how to define and configure custom EL functions is mentioned somewhere near the bottom of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995

Comment: @blausC, Do u have any suggestion to make the disabled feature of text input field work only for the first time when the page is loaded, since if I submit the form and return back from the servlet, the check fields are checked where as the fields are disabled !
How can I make it enabled when the page is loaded for the second time?

Comment: Do the same as you did for checkboxes, but then the other way round and with `disabled`, e.g. `${communicationWays.emailOption ? '' : 'disabled'}` on the email field.

Comment: I cannot find any words to express my thanks for u Mr BalusC, I wish one day I can have a flexible thinking like u.
Many thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanx :)