# Extend h:outputText for custom functionality

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jstl, jsf-1.2

I have been using JSF + RF for over 2 years and have'nt had a chance to extend the existing capabilities of components.

Now the requirement is I have to trim the string and display it if it is more than 25 characters.

This has been achieved as below

```
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="#{fn:length(teststep.name) > 25}">
                                <h:outputText title="#{teststep.name}" value="#{fn:substring(teststep.name, 0, 25)}..."/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <h:outputText title="#{teststep.name}" value="#{teststep.name}"/>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
```

But I use this code in lot many places (and want to avoid boilerplate code of 8 lines everytime) so thought of custom h:outputText to provide trim functionality.

Could you let me know how would I write a custom tag in JSF

Regards,
Satya

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you're using JSP not Facelets, put the content in a `.tag` file in `/WEB-INF`, like `/WEB-INF/tags/outputLimitedText.tag`.

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{fn:length(value) > maxlength}">
        <h:outputText title="#{value}" value="#{fn:substring(value, 0, maxlength)}..."/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <h:outputText title="#{value}" value="#{value}"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Then you can reference it as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %> 
...
<my:outputLimitedText value="#{teststep.name}" maxlength="25" />
```

---

You could also use a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html).

```
<h:outputText title="#{teststep.name}" value="#{teststep.name}">
    <f:converter converterId="substringConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="maxlength" value="25" />
</h:outputText>
```

with

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String string = (String) value;
    int maxlength = Integer.valueOf((String) component.getAttributes().get("maxlength"));

    if (string.length() > maxlength) {
        return string.substring(0, maxlength) + "...";
    } else {
        return string;
    }
}
```

---

You could also create a custom EL function. So that you end up with

```
<h:outputText title="#{teststep.name}" value="#{util:ellipsis(teststep.name, 25)}">
```

A concrete example of the EL function is given in this answer: [How to concatenate Strings in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838102/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-el/6847212#6847212)

Comment: I have tried the 1st solution and that didnt impress me :) but would like to do something like <h:outputText title="#{value}" value="#{value}" trimByChars="25"/> . Is that by any chance possible to still retain features of h:outputText and only add some more capabilities?

Comment: I will give a try for the third option, seems to be some new learning for me :) . Thanks a lot BalusC

Comment: Adding a new attribute to an existing component is only possible by a custom component, not a custom tag. This is a very tedious work. You've to copy **all** existing tag attributes as it's not possible to inherit from existing tags. Easier would be to provide the extra attribute as `<f:attribute>` and override the default `Renderer`.