# How do I parse through a URL path, get the filename, then replace the file extension using JSTL and Java scriptlet

Tags: java, string, parsing, jstl, scriptlet

I need to get "filename" from a URL

Here I am declaring

```
<p:out var="path" value="${webObject.path}" scope="page"/>
<c:set var="string1" value="${path}" />
<p:out value="${string1}" />
```

this returns "dir1/dir2/dir3/filename.xml" on the webpage

What I need is a Java Scriptlet that takes the URL being produced (dir1/.../filename.xml) and gets the 'filename' with no directories in front and no .xml at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use *Scriptlets*. Use [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) in [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

```xml
<c:set var="pathparts" value="${fn:split(path, '/')}" />                <!-- String[] with values "dir1", "dir2", "dir3" and "filename.xml" -->
<c:set var="filename" value="${pathparts[fn:length(pathparts) - 1]}" /> <!-- Last item of String[]: "filename.xml" -->
<c:set var="basename" value="${fn:split(filename, '.')[0]}" />          <!-- Result: "filename" -->
```

If you really need to write Java code for this, consider an EL function. E.g.

```xml
<c:set var="basename" value="${util:basename(path)}" />
```

with

```
public static String basename(String path) {
    String[] pathparts = path.split("/");
    String filename = pathparts[pathparts.length - 1];
    return filename.split("\\.")[0];
}
```

How to register an EL function, look at the example somewhere near bottom of [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995).