# Check if Cookie exists with JSP EL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I am trying to check if a cookie exists on a JSP page using the Expression Language.

I have a cookie called `persist` which is set to either empty string or "checked".

If would like to check if the `persist` cookie exists.

I have tried the following:

`<c:if test="${cookie.persist == null}">`

`<c:if test="${empty cookie.persist}">`

Both of the above statements are `true` when the value of the `persist` cookie is the empty string and false when the value of the cookie is `checked`.

How do I distinguish between a cookie with the empty string as its value, and a cookie that does not exist.

(Note: I can easily work around this problem by assigning a non empty value to the cookie instead of the empty string.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Closest what you can get is to check the cookie name in the request `cookie` header.

```html
<c:if test="${fn:contains(header.cookie, 'persist=')}">
```

However, when there's another cookie with name `foopersist`, it fails.

If your container supports EL 2.2 (all Servlet 3.0 containers like Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc do) then you could just use `Map#containsKey()`.

```html
<c:if test="${cookie.containsKey('persist')}">
```

If yours doesn't, best what you can do is to create an EL function (more concrete declaration example can be found somewhere near bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995)):

```html
<c:if test="${util:mapContainsKey(cookie, 'persist')}">
```

with

```java
public static boolean mapContainsKey(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    return map.containsKey(key);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the 2nd approach did not seem to work for me. I got the same results as using `<c:if test="${empty cookie.persist}">`

Comment: The first approach works fine. My cookies have an application prefix on them so I should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to detect that it either doesn't exist or is empty.

EDIT: ah. To verify that it doesn't exist, it must be null and not empty.

```
    <c:if test="${cookie.persist == null && cookie.persist != ''}">
   Cookie doesn't exist
    </c:if>
```

Comment: I am just trying to check that the cookie does NOT exist.

Comment: When I use `${cookie.persist == null}` it returns true if the cookie exists AND is set to '' (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

use the cookie map to check that cookie exists or not
`${cookie["persist"] == null}`

I hope it works

Comment: Sorry did not work. `${cookie["persist"] == null}` gave the same result as `${cookie.persist == null}`

Answer (score 0):

if using Tomcat 6+

```
<c:if test="${ ! empty cookie['persist']}"> 
Cookie doesn't exist
</c:if>
```

Comment: This expression doesn't check if there is a cookie, but if there is a cookie value. OP's concrete problem is that it would also pass when the cookie exists but contains an empty value. Please re-read the question and all the answers.