# How to read value of three cookies using JSTL?

Tags: jsp, cookies, jstl

I have three cookies, two of them are used to keep the details of user (name and id) and the other one is to keep the type of user. I need to show a specific message based on type of user which is retrieved from one of the cookies.

I have the following working code but it is a bit complex, I am wondering if there is any efficient way to do it.

```
<c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="IdCookie">
     <c:if test="${IdCookie.key == 'UserID'}">   << if UserID cookie is found

            <c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="nameCookie">

               <c:if test="${nameCookie.key == 'User'}"> << if User cookie is found

                      <p>${IdCookie.value.value} &nbsp; ${nameCookie.value.value}</p>
                      <c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="typeCookie">                                     
                                <c:if test="${typeCookie.key == 'Type'}"> << if Type cookie is found

                                     <c:if test="${typeCookie.value == 'One'}">
                                         <p>,Your type is one </p>
                                     </c:if>
                                     <c:if test="${typeCookie.value == '0'}">
                                         <p>,Your type is NOT one </p>
                                      </c:if>

                                 </c:if>

                      </c:forEach>
               </c:if>

             </c:forEach>
     </c:if>

 </c:forEach>
```

**Output**

```
   Cookies' values >> 1 Alex 0
   output >> 1 Alex,Your type is Not one 
   Cookies' values >>  1 Jack One
   output >> 1 Jack,Your type is one
```

Comment: first thing is to have separate for loops for each part of your output to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

See [Getting cookie in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116040/getting-cookie-in-jsp)

You can make this a lot simpler this way:

```
<p>${cookie['UserId'].value} ${cookie['User'].value}, 
<c:if test="${cookie['Type'].value == 'One'}">
  ,Your type is one
</c:if>
<c:if test="${cookie['Type'].value == '0'}">
  ,Your type is NOT one
</c:if></p>
```

Making it even simpeler by using the ternary operator (`?:`) is left an an exercise for the reader :).

If you want to check if the cookie exists first, see this one: [Check if Cookie exists with JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395176/check-if-cookie-exists-with-jsp-el)

so you could do:

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(header.cookie, 'User=') and fn:contains(header.cookie, 'Type=') and fn:contains(header.cookie, 'UserId=')}">
```

When this gets to complex, I would advise to wrap it in a bean though.

Comment: great thanks, but need to make sure those UserID and User cookies exist before showing the value of Type cookie.

Comment: the userId and user cookies shows javax.servlet.http.Cookie@29b3d3eas as well.