# render currency symbol based on locale

Tags: jsp, internationalization, jstl, locale, currency

I have a JSP with some monetary amounts in £s.   I want people viewing the same page from the US to see $ symbol instead of £s.  (Forget for a moment that the values ought to be converted as well).

I am using this JSTL solution to set the locale

```
<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
```

which works perfectly for output fields like this:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${myOutputAmount}" />
```

but there are also some input fields that have the £ on its own before the input box, e.g.:

```
£<input type="text" id="myInputAmount"/>
```

How can I use that locale to show the relevant currency symbol instead of £?

I have searched and found solutions for iPhone, PHP, android, C# and Java.  I could implement a Java solution in my JSP but the JSTL one was so neat I'm sure there must be an easy way, tapping into however that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no JSTL tag for this.

In plain Java you could get it by [`Currency#getSymbol()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol%28%29) as follows:

```
String currencySymbol = Currency.getInstance(new Locale(language)).getSymbol();
// ...
```

You could wrap it around in a Javabean getter, an EL function or maybe a (*shudder*) scriptlet. You can find a concrete example of how to create an EL function near the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995).

---

**Update:** you could use this "hack" to get the currency symbol out of a `<fmt:formatNumber>`:

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="currencyExample" value="${0}" type="currency" maxFractionDigits="0" />
<c:set var="currencySymbol" value="${fn:replace(currencyExample, '0', '')}" />
...
${currencySymbol}<input type="text" name="amount" />
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC.  I went for the EL option.  It works, except that:  (a) I had to split my JSTL "language" variable into "language" and "country", e.g. "en_US" into "en" and "US" for the Locale constructor; (b) it returns "USD" when I want "$".  From what I've read I think this is because of my default locale?  I'm looking into it...

Comment: Perhaps I should have said earlier that my "language" variable comes from my setting `session.setAttribute("language", "en_US");` server-side

Comment: I see. Well, the "hack" in my updated answer should work out for you.

Comment: Indeed it does!  I'm happy with that.  Thanks, you are a star.