# how to determine currency symbol of current locale in POSIX shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting, posix, locale, currency

ahoy all.

while finding a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798358/how-to-determine-which-character-is-used-as-decimal-separator-radix-point-or-t) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72795026/format-currency-in-bash) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845638/how-do-i-change-the-decimal-separator-in-the-printf-command-in-bash) to determining the locale's decimal separator (AKA radix point, thousands separator) in a shell script, the only [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013950/print-currency-number-format-in-php) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313118/render-currency-symbol-based-on-locale) i have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969439/how-to-get-the-currency-symbol-for-particular-country-using-locale) related to obtaining the currency symbol of the current locale are specific to a programming language (e.g. PHP, Java, etc).  however surprisingly i cannot yet find a solution which can be used in a POSIX shell script.  i have come across references to locale variables like `LC_MONETARY` and `LC_CURRENCY` but have not yet stumbled upon a way to access them from the shell as they are not in the default environment of a normal bash/dash login.

as always thanks for reading and for any answers and comments.

peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some more spelunking in the `locale` command i have discovered the following method for getting the currency symbol of the current locale:

```
locale currency_symbol
```

this command and keyword returns the appropriate currency symbol of the current locale

```
$ LANG=it_IT.UTF-8 locale currency_symbol
€

$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 locale currency_symbol
$
```

of course any other solutions and options, including ones that avoid the execution of an external command (i.e. `locale`) and a sub-process, are always appreciated :)

Comment: `locale currency_symbol` doesn't output anything on my macOS

Comment: It does for me, @Fravadona.  What locale does `locale` with no args say you're in?  Perhaps you're in one with no defined _currency_symbol_ (like C or POSIX).

Comment: @pilcrow You're right, `locale` gives me this: `LANG="en_US.utf8"` `LC_MONETARY="C"` `LC_ALL=` (the others are all defined as `C`)

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Bash 4.3 and higher:

```
declare -A lc_monetary
while IFS='=' read -d $'\n' -r k v; do
    lc_monetary[$k]="$v"
done < <(locale -k LC_MONETARY)
```

You can then access all values related to `LC_MONETARY` via the associative array `lc_monetary`. For example, to access the currency symbol:

```
currsym=lc_numeric["currency_symbol"]
```

To get the full list of keys and values, use

```
declare -p lc_monetary
```

For the list of keys, do

```
echo "${!lc_monetary[@]}"
```

See the [locale (5) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/locale) for the different keys and their meaning.

Comment: while i am looking for a POSIX solution as mentioned in my question, thanks for this bash option