# How to translate JSP servlet which calls an object method into JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I just started to use JSTL for my project, but sorry to say it's really confusing to me.

I originally used `Number.java`

```
package com.mycompany
public class Number {
  private int total;
  public static int add (int x, int y) {
    return total;
}
```

And in `showNumber.jsp` i could just use

```
<%@page import= "com.mycompany.Number" %>
```

and inline use `<%= Number.add(5,6) %>`

How can I rewrite this part in `JSTL`?
Is that also possible to import the class `Number.java`?
I tried so many different things, e.g. `<c:out value="${Number}.add(5,6)" />`, but still cannot find a solution. Thanks.

---

Edited: 
I use @Victor's approach, and it does work. In my case, I need to reuse other's variable from spring framework, say `NumberTwo.java` and `totalTwo` as private variable inside. And added "100" to this `totalTwo`.

For the src where i need to use it is `<spring:param name="secondNumber" value ="${NumberTwo.totalTwo}" />`.

However, intutively i used `(int) pageContext.getAttribute("NumberTwo.totalTwo")`, it always returned me `null`.

The other workaround is 
first `<c:set var="result" value="${NumberTwo.totalTwo}" />` 
then `<% String result = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("result"); %>`
and then `<%= Number.add(result, 100) %>`

Comment: the `add` is just an simplified example for function usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to arbitrarily call methods with JSTL, the function capabilities of JSTL are very limited: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html . But it's still possible to use your *Number* class. Here the workaround:

```
<%@page import= "com.mycompany.Number" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%
    pageContext.setAttribute("addResult", Number.add(7, 8));
%>
<html>
<body>
  JSP 1.x: Result is: <c:out value="${addResult}" /><br/>
  JSP 2.x: Result is: ${addResult}
</body>
</html>
```

With *pageContext.setAttribute()* the method result is stored in the page context, and the JSTL tags can access values (attributes) stored in that context.

Note: the second output line "*Result is: ${result}*" works only with JSP 2 afaik.

Comment: Thank you so much. This does help a lot. One of my related problem is, I might need to reuse this `${addResult}` in the scriptlet. So for example, `Number.add("${addResult}, "7")`. Based on this workaround, I wonder how to use the things in JSTL back to scriptlet. Thanks.

Comment: I guess i can use `(String) pageContext.getAttribute("addResult") `to reuse this variable (maybe not a standard way). However, the new problem is, when i worked with other people, i could not use `pageContext` to retrieve their data via `getAttribute`. The result always show me "null". If this is a right approach, how could I know where to `getArribute`?

Comment: I find a way to work around:

The source ==> for `foo.java` and `bar` (the private variable) in `<spring:param name="foobar" value ="${foo.bar}" />`. If I want `${foo.bar}` and try `(String) pageContext.getAttribute("foo.bar")`, it always returns me `null`. The solution ==> first `<c:set var="result" value="${foo.bar}" />`  then `<% String result = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("result"); %>` before i reuse `result` in my scriptlet. This approach works, but just cumbersome to `<c:set>` before `.getAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'usebean' tag as in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="1.2">
<!-- UseBean.jsp
     Copyright (c) 2002 by Dr. Herong Yang
-->
<html><body>
<jsp:directive.page import="CacheBean"/>
<jsp:useBean id="b" class="CacheBean"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="b" property="text" value="Hello world!"/>
Property from my Bean: 
<jsp:getProperty name="b" property="text"/>
<br/>
Info from my Bean: 
<jsp:expression>b.getInfo()</jsp:expression>
</body></html>
</jsp:root>
```

Where:

```
/**
 * CacheBean.java
 * Copyright (c) 2002 by Dr. Herong Yang. All rights reserved.
 */
public class CacheBean {
  private String text = "null";
  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }
  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
  public String getInfo() {
    return "My JavaBean - Version 1.00"
  }
}
```

CREDIT TO:  http://www.herongyang.com/jsp/usebean.html

Comment: Thanks, but i might still need to interact with others' EF variable like `${xxxx}`. I hope i can know how i can reuse such variable in the jsp:usebean.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at EL functions in BalusC's answer at
[Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)
also 
look at "Using Custom Methods in EL"  at
http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/jstl-el.shtml
look at Functions  at
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html

Comment: This seems also to work, but i hope i can see a way to get rid of maintaining another tag library descriptor (.tld) file.