# URL rooting Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets

The incoming request URL looks like: `/{root}/Details/View/{id}`. I have a servlet `DetailsController` which based on if a person is logged in or not will show either the "Edit" view or the "Details" view:

```
if (user != null) {
    detailsViewModel.setUser((User) user);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/edit.jsp").forward(request, response);
} else {
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/details.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

In the edit view there is a form that has an `action="Update"` and I just want it to go to the `UpdateController` on `/{root}/Update` but it's trying to go `/{root}/Details/View/{id}/Update`. I've set the context root but to avail.

If I put `action="/Update"`, it tries to go `localhost:8080/Update` without the root. Is this because I am using the forward? How can I fix this? Let me know if I'm missing details you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepend the context path in the form action URL with help of [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) in EL.

```xml
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Update">
```

This way it becomes `"/{root}/Update"`.

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735)