# JSP redirect/forward

Tags: jsp, redirect, forward

I have this page:

http://example.com/folder/page.jsp

I would like to redirect/forward, in case of error/exception to the page http://example.com/page.jsp
(as you can see the path is different).

doing `<jsp:forward page="/page.jsp">` does work but all css and img ref now searches for http://example.com/folder/css , http://example.com/folder/img , without keeping the example.com/page.jsp layout.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp

Answer (score 1):

Reference you css, javascript and images in a absolute way like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/my.css" />
```

Comment: Better if your prepend ${pageContext.request.contextPath} to your absolute href value.

Comment: @craftsman Thanks! How to change absolue href value on css, as well? (background url)