# how to get the base url from jsp request object?

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

How to get the base url from the jsp request object? 
http://localhost:8080/SOMETHING/index.jsp, but I want the part till index.jsp, how is it possible in jsp?

Comment: there are many ways. Why exactly do you need it?

Comment: I have some requirement for which I need the url of the web container. So, I need a path till http://localhost:8080/my_web_container.

Comment: this is now "web container", but "context". And do you need it absolute, or relative (to the host)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

So, you want the *base URL*? You can get it in a servlet as follows:

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String baseURL = url.substring(0, url.length() - request.getRequestURI().length()) + request.getContextPath() + "/";
// ...
```

Or in a JSP, as `<base>`, with little help of JSTL:

```xml
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="url">${req.requestURL}</c:set>
<c:set var="uri" value="${req.requestURI}" />
...
<head>
    <base href="${fn:substring(url, 0, fn:length(url) - fn:length(uri))}${req.contextPath}/" />
</head>
```

Note that this does not include the port number when it's already the default port number, such as 80. The `java.net.URL` doesn't take this into account.

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735)

Comment: what is the reason that setting the `var` for the "url" follows different syntax than setting the `var` for "req" and "uri" ?

Answer (score 18):

JSP variant of [Bozho's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271142/433626) answer:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}:${req.serverPort}${req.contextPath}" />
```

Comment: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` yields nothing for `/admin/home`.

Answer (score 14):

```
new URL(request.getScheme(), 
        request.getServerName(), 
        request.getServerPort(), 
        request.getContextPath());
```

Comment: what you you mean "till"? It will generate what you want, I think. Try it.

Comment: Note that this will even for default port numbers (http+80 and https+443) still include the port number in the final result. This is not always desireable, for sure not if the URL is to be used in some redirect URL or as `<base>` URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is one major flaw in @BalusC accepted answer though. Substring should start from 0 and not 1. Instead of

```
<base href="${fn:replace(req.requestURL, fn:substring(uri, 1, fn:length(uri)), req.contextPath)}" />
```

it should be

```
<base href="${fn:replace(req.requestURL, fn:substring(uri, 0, fn:length(uri)), req.contextPath)}" />
```

With 1 you get double forward slash: `http://localhost:8080//appcontext/`
With 0 you get, `http://localhost:21080/appcontext/`

In my application, request.getSession(false) always returned null when it was ending in double slash!!!

Answer (score -3):

Instead of doing all of that, just do this:

```
request.getServerName().toString()
```

Answer (score -3):

just use isSecure()

{<%=request.isSecure()?"https":"http:"%>}