# Static files are served in Spring MVC with tomcat 7 in Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have been searching on the net and ripping my hair on how to solve this issue for almost 3 weeks, but I can't find the reason why my static files are served in Spring MVC with tomcat 7 in my local Windows, but not in our server on Linux(Ubuntu). Below I have described my projects file structure and all my relevant files:

[image]

**web.xml:**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.bakuparkingaz.util.BakuParkingServletContext</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**app-context.xml:**

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bakuparkingaz"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

**AdminController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
/.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
    public String admin() {

        return "resources/admin/index.html";
    }
}
```

So now when I call http://localhost:8080/admin I get the pretty styled page, but on the server http://8.8.8.8/project/admin (I have deployed my war file as project.war to tomcats webapp folder) results in an ugly styleless html page. Why my static files won't serve on the linux server?

**UPDATE**:
**admin/index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <base href="/resources/admin/">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BP Admin</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/semantic.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="ui left vertical labeled icon menu sidebar" id="left-menu">

  <a class="item">
      <i class="home icon"></i>
      Home
  </a>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="text center"><p>Copyright (c) 2015 - BakuParking</p> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/my.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The context paths differ, maybe you could try to add a [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag in the <head> of your index.html.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing what you have suggested right now, but I think it's only for simplicity, I don't think it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On localhost, your app is on the root context. On 8.8.8.8, your app is on the context `/project`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath().

Try to use an absolute value in your `<base>` tag, which will then depend on the environment:

For localhost:

```html
<base href="http://localhost:8080/" />
```

For 8.8.8.8:

```html
<base href="http://8.8.8.8/project/" />
```

Then, use the following relative paths for both environments:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/admin/css/normalize.css" />
<script src="/resources/admin/js/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

---

You'll see a method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271253/1225328) to set the `<base>` tag dynamically.

Comment: "The context paths differ" - I didn't understand the statement at first, but that was actually the correct answer. What a stupid mistake was that. Thank you, I have solved the issue!