# How do I find/get my relative paths when using restful java and corresponding JSPs

Tags: java, jsp, rest, restful-url

Say I have a Contoller.java that has these 3 functions to direct traffic to the 3 jsps (index.jsp, create.jsp, show.jsp)

```
public class Controller
{

  @GET
  @Path("/index")
  public void index(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
  @Context HttpServletResponse response)
  {
      //If I get hit I redirect to index.jsp

  }

  @POST
  @Path("/create")
  public void create(@FormParam ("name") String name, @Context HttpServletRequest     request)
  @Context HttpServletResponse response
  {
       //if i get hit I take the form param name do stuff to create new instance of whatever

  }

  @GET
  @Path("/show/{id}")
  public void show (@PathParam(id) String id, @Context HttpServletRequest request,
  @Context HttpServletResponse response)
  {
      //if I get hit I show the object with the given id from the url

  }
}
```

In my constituent JSP

**index.jsp**
just a simple page to display created types - easy enough

**create.jsp**
Just form to create the type and redirect back to index.jsp on submit
-->Problem: link back to index.jsp would be `<a href="index">index</a>`

**show.jsp**
just a form with the defualt values of the selected instance and a button to return to index
--Problem: link back to index.jsp would be `<a href="../index">index</a>`

Question: How do I reference the same path in different pages without
being ambiguous like this. Does rest
api offer a way to around this without
having to find out where your page is
relative to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use domain-relative links. I.e., let it start with `/`. You can obtain the context path dynamically by [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29).

```xml
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index">index</a>
```

It'll end up in HTML like as

```xml
<a href="/yourwebappcontextpath/index">index</a>
```

If you get tired of repeating it everytime, use the `<base>`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735).