# Serving javascript/jsf resources from a jsf app

Tags: javascript, file, jsf, richfaces

I have a "/js/ajax-error.js" file that I would to serve in a "richfaces way" as follows: **"/js/ajax-error.js.jsf"** so that I use that kind of jsf variables in my js file: **"#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}"**.

Is that possible? I have tried prefixing my js file with xhtml: it does not work.

I use richfaces + jsf 2.0 + servlet 3.0

Can anyone please help?

(added) Is there not a clean **JSF** way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sole purpose is to serve it "the Richfaces way" (it's actually the JSF 2.0 way), then use `<h:outputScript>`. Put the file in `/resources/js/ajax-error.js` of public webcontent (the main path `/resources` is mandatory and its name cannot be changed). Then reference it as follows:

```
<h:outputScript name="js/ajax-error.js" />
```

Regardless of its location in the template, it'll be generated into the HTML `<head>` like follows assuming that your `FacesServlet` is mapped on `*.jsf`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/js/ajax-error.js.jsf"></script>
```

But that doesn't offer you EL support! You won't be able to use `#{}` in that script. Only in stylesheets which are included by `<h:outputStylesheet>` the `#{}` is supported in order to locate background images the JSF 2.0 `#{resource['logo.png']}` way, but nothing more than that.

In your particular case, I'd rather reference `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}` (or its shorter and more popular counterpart `#{request.contextPath}`) in the HTML `<base>` tag or some global JS variable or the HTML `data` attribute. If set as `<base>`, all relative links will be relative to it, also in JS.

#### See also:

- [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url)
- [How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/changing-the-image-of-a-hcommandbutton-using-css) (shows `h:outputStylesheet` example)

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Can you please elaborate on how to use the <base> tag and the global js variable?

Comment: Check the "See also" link for the `<base>` example. As to global JS variable, just add something like `<script>var base = '#{request.contextPath}';</script>` to your `<head>`. It'll be available as global variable `base` in all JavaScripts which are invoked after that line is been initialized.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I see. I am realizing I did not include enough information about my problem and I think it would be more appropriate to open a second thread.

Comment: Woah I was trying to get the context in Javascript with something like window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] == '' ? '' : '/'+window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]; which of course,was flawed. <script>var base = '#{request.contextPath}';</script> is great!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do that, but I strongly suggest that you don't.  Keep your JavaScript clean and cacheable.

A common pattern used to arrange for server-side data to be available to JavaScript is to drop values into "data-" attributes on appropriate parts of the HTML.  For example, "global" information (say, stuff about the user's session, like user name, company name, etc) can be attached to the `<body>`:

```
<body data-username='John Phillip Sousa' data-registered='05 Jul 1903'>
```

Now the JavaScript can find out the username and registration date just by grabbing the data attributes off the `<body>` tag. *edit* like this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var username = body.getAttribute("data-username");
var registrationDate = body.getAttribute("data-registered");
```

Comment: "Now the JavaScript can find out the username and registration date just by grabbing the data attributes off the <body> tag." Thanks. How do you do that?

Comment: Well it depends on whether you're using a JavaScript framework, but they're just attributes - I'll update the answer.