# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: jsf-2.2, myfaces, tomee-7

I'm trying to build a very simple web-app, where a template xhtml file is placed in a jar placed in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. The structure of this jar is as follows:

```
META-INF/
  faces-config.xml
  resources
    template.xhtml
```

The content of my `index.xhtml` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">


<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

And finally, my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <description>For Apache MyFaces: need to refresh transient build or an IllegalStateException may occur in visitTree.</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS_PRESERVE_STATE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I'm using a TomEE 7.0.2 server, which uses a MyFaces 2.2.11 implementation. Still, I'm getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /template.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:308)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.getRelativePath(DefaultFacelet.java:470)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:552)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:151)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:477)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:200)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376115/absolute-path-name-in-my-template-to-get-resources ???

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I need to place the template in a different jar, not in a different folder in the main war.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Are you sure the other jar is on the classpath?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Declaring, for example, a managed bean in the dependant jar and trying to access this from `index.xhtml`, works perfectly fine.