# How to: specify a context path  for links in a JSF application?

Tags: java, jsf, contextpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url)

How do i specify a context path for JSF application so that I dont need to provide full urls to links in my code ?

Using Facelets 2.0

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for the link! Is it **required** to specify the base URL path while writing URLs outside of the composite components as well(asking since the question you linked to, there the OP had asked for composite components & Previously my URLs in `<h:outputLink/>` and `<a>` used to work fine (using relative URLs) without specifying the base path but when I started adding composite components these URLs dont append the base path on their own)

Comment: Not required, but recommended so that you don't need to fiddle with relative paths whenever you move files or change URLs.