# Is there something better to generate absolute links?

Tags: jsf-2

Is a better way to generate absolute links in JSF 2.0 ? Right now I'm using `<h:outputLink/>` in that ugly way with `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}` like below. I don't want to use JSTL and `<c:url />`

```
<h:outputLink value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/pages/home.jsf">Home</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: What about navigation rules ?

Comment: No navigation rules. I need only to find a simple way in JSF 2.0 to make links generated with context-path automatically. In normal way i use `<c:url />`, but it is requirement that no use JSTL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can shorten `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}` to `#{request.contextPath}`. You can even get rid of it to use [HTML `<base>` tag instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag/1889957#1889957).

In this particular case, better is to use [`<h:link>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) instead. It can take a context-relative navigation case path in `outcome` attribute:

```
<h:link value="Home" outcome="pages/home" />
```

JSF will take care about adding the right context path and `FacesServlet` mapping while generating the `<a>` element:

```
<a href="/contextname/pages/home.jsf">Home</a>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Implicit navigation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation)
- [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url/6878393#6878393)

Comment: What if I don't have outcome or navigation rule, for example: `<h:link value="download" outcome="res/file.pdf" />`. This give an error: `Unable to find matching navigation case from view ID '/pages/home.xhtml' for outcome 'res/file.pdf'`

Comment: Then use `<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/res/file.pdf">Download</h:outputLink>` or just `<a href="#{request.contextPath}/res/file.pdf">Download</a>` or use HTML `<base>`.