# How do I get the script page I am running from the Browser URL

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Is there anyway in JSF to get the URL, the scriptname, from the address bar that refers to the page I am on? What would that way be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the request URI in the backing bean you'd need to grab the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) from under the JSF's covers:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
// ...
```

It offers [several methods](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to get information about the request, such as `getRequestURI()`. Most of them are also available through `getRequestXXX()` methods of the [`ExternalContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html), but the request URI not.

In the view, you can get it by `#{request}`. E.g.

```html
<a href="#{request.requestURI}">Click here to navigate recursively</a>
```

Alternatively, if you're *actually* interested in the JSF view ID (the "script name" as you say yourself), then rather use [`UIViewRoot#getViewId()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId%28%29):

```
String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
// ...
```

or in the view itself:

```html
<a href="#{request.contextPath}#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId}">Click here to navigate recursively</a>
```

or without the context path:

```html
<h:link outcome="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId}" value="Click here to navigate recursively" />
```

#### Related:

- [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url)