# Image Src for calling a Servlet

Tags: java, image, jsf, servlets, src

I want to call a Servlet from img src. I have defined a Servlet class with name ImageProducerServlet and registered it in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>ImageProducerServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.company.servlet.ImageProducerServlet</servlet-class>    
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ImageProducerServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/imageproducerservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this servlet's doGet I just wrote a `System.out`. Now From the JSF page I am calling that servlet as:

```
<img src="/imageProducerServlet" id="id"/>
```

I was expecting that it would print the System.out! But it doesn't.

The URL for the page where the img is added is:

> http://localhost:7101/mycompany/faces/home

If I write in the address bar the follwoing URL:

> http://localhost:7101/mycompany/imageproducerservlet

and press enter then the servlet's doGet is executing.

I am unable to find it's solution.

It will be very helpful if I get your suggestions.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is working:

```
http://localhost:7101/mycompany/imageproducerservlet
```

then you need your img tag to look like that:

```
<img src="/mycompany/imageProducerServlet" id="id"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just say

```
<img src="imageProducerServlet" id="id"/>
```

or

```
<img src="/mycompany/imageProducerServlet" id="id"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend the context path. You preferably won't hardcode it as the context path is a server-controlled setting. You can obtain it from the HTTP request as follows:

```html
<img src="#{request.contextPath}/imageProducerServlet" id="id"/>
```

An alternative is to use the HTML `<base>` tag and set it to the URL of the context root. This way every URL which doesn't start with `/` will be relative to it.

#### See also:

- [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url)