# print jfreechart on IE

Tags: internet-explorer-11, jfreechart

I print a jfreechart on Internet Explorer and i got a blank page.
Actually, the version of my IE is 11.0.9600.18697CO, 11.0.43 (KB4021558).

I hadn't this problem with older version IE.

I haven't this problme on Chrome and Firefox.

My freechart is generated on the server, showed on the client by a servlet and deleted on the server (it is a jfreechart-one time]).

On the console debug of IE, when i execute window.print(); there are requets sended to server. I think it caused problem (although http code = 200).

If i don't delete the chart on the server, i have no problem.

Someone hit the same problem? Solution?
thanks a lot,
best regards

Answer (score 1):

In a servlet context using [`ChartUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html), instead of using one of the `save…` methods, try using the corresponding `write…` method.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws … {
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    …
    //ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file, chart, …);
    ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, …);
}
```

> Could you explain why? I am using [`ServletUtilities.saveChartAsPNG()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/servlet/ServletUtilities.html#saveChartAsPNG-org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart-int-int-org.jfree.chart.ChartRenderingInfo-javax.servlet.http.HttpSession-)

I'm guessing that there's a race condition that allows the file to be deleted prematurely. If you need the `ChartRenderingInfo`, the corresponding `ChartUtilities` method would likely be [`writeChartAsPNG()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html#writeChartAsPNG-java.io.OutputStream-org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart-int-int-org.jfree.chart.ChartRenderingInfo-). If you can't switch, use a [`DelayQueue<File>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) to defer deleting the temporary file.

Comment: could you explain why? I am using [http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/servlet/ServletUtilities.html#saveChartAsPNG-org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart-int-int-org.jfree.chart.ChartRenderingInfo-javax.servlet.http.HttpSession-]ServletUtilities.saveChartAsPNG

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: I can't switch ServletUtilities.saveChartAsPNG to ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG because i do the graph and show it in one jsp file, with <img> tag, eg, <img src="/DisplayChart?filename=xxx>. I think i will try the chart without oneTime and then use cron (system or spring) to delete the file after some moment!

Comment: The `src` doesn't have to be a file; if can be a servlet, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9835061/230513).