# How to reach the WebContent folder from a web service method

Tags: java, jax-ws

I want to reach a file in WebContent folder from a method in a web service in the same project. For example:

```
@WebMethod
public String test() {
     File configFile = new File("config.xml");
     return configFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

It returns "/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/config.xml". I want to get to a file in the directory "/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/my_project_name/" folder. How can I get to it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this that I use is:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myFile.txt").getPath()
```

This gives the path of any file `myFile.txt` placed in `/WEB-INF/classes/` directory inside the `WebContent` folder of the WebApp.

In Eclipse JEE environment you need to keep the file `myFile.txt`, that you may want to read within the Web Service, in the `src` folder for it to be transported to the `/WEB-INF/classes/` folder by the deployer.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I understand that yours is an JAXWS webservice.

In jaxws, you can get the HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServletContext,

Have a private variable in your webservice class and annotate it in this way

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
```

And then in your method, you can get the ServletContext this way

```
ServletContext servletContext =
    (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
```

From servletContext, you can get the path.

Suppose if you need to get HttpServletRequest, you can get it in this way

```
HttpServletRequest request =
            (HttpServletRequest) context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
```

and you can get the context path of your app like

```
request.getContextPath() ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I use this statement for creating a new file, but it doesn't work:  `String filePath = String.format("%s%s%s", request.getContextPath(), File.separatorChar, "config.xml"); File configFile = new File(filePath);`

Comment: try to get it as input stream rather : say for ex             ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) context
    .getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
     servletContext.getContextPath() + "/" + fileName);

Answer (score 1):

Add the following parameter to your web service class:

```
@Context
ServletContext context;
```

Then, supposing your `config.xml` file is in the `WebContent` folder, you can get its absolute path by invoking the method `context.getRealPath(String)`. Using your example code it would be:

```
@WebMethod
public String test() {
     File configFile = new File(context.getRealPath("config.xml"));
     return configFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Or directly, without passing by a File object:

```
@WebMethod
public String test() {
     return context.getRealPath("config.xml");
}
```