# jsf primefaces how navigate to page in up folder

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I cannot find out how navigate to page located in upper dir. Is it possible at all?
here is my project structure:

[image]

question:
how should line `<ui:composition template="web2/web/index.xhtml">` looks like in the code of any page from folder **main_pages** to include `index.xhtml` and how to insert i.e. image from **images** folder (I can't get right path, io.exception still):
onas.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      >
    <h:body>

        <ui:composition template="web2/web/index.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="centerContent">
                    <h:form>
                        <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
                        <p:panelGrid styleClass="myPanel">
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column>
                        <ui:param name="mainTag" value="Z chęcią odpowiemy" />
                <h2>Zapytaj</h2>
                        <h4>#{mainTag}</h4></p:column>
                            </p:row>
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column><p:inputTextarea styleClass="myTextArea" autoResize="true" value="#{mySendBean.mailContent}"/></p:column>
                                <p:column>
                        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{mySendBean.sendMail2()}" value="Wyślij" update="msg">
            </h:commandButton>
                                    </p:column>
                            </p:row>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </h:form>
            </ui:define>


        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

when I change composition to be:

```
<ui:composition template="#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml">
```

I get error:

```
/onas.xhtml @11,74 <ui:composition template="#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml"> Invalid path : /web2/faces/index.xhtml
```

or if I add /faces/:

```
/onas.xhtml @11,74 <ui:composition template="#{request.contextPath}/faces/index.xhtml"> Invalid path : /web2/faces/index.xhtml
```

Comment: Did you try requestContextpath ?

Comment: Duplicate content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Comment: @RongNK see update: you might consider undownvoting and upvote

Comment: I think you should research via book via internet, it is popular question, not only for jsf, i downvoted for that reason, sorry if it made you boring !

Comment: @RongNK,ok, nevermind, and believe me I made research, I never ask without it, though sometimes what seems easy in some cases is so hard to resolve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All paths in `<ui:xxx>` components are absolute to the webcontent root, which is the "Web Pages" folder. Also, you should prefer using absolute paths starting with `/` instead of relative paths.

So, this should do:

```
<ui:composition template="/index.xhtml">
```

The `#{request.contextPath}` is only necessary when you want to manually create an URL (for the enduser). The `/faces` is only necessary when you want to invoke the JSF mapping on it.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's recommended to put template files in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent direct access.

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)

Comment: tahnk you very much. I have changed it to be <ui:composition template="/index.xhtml"> in my subpage, then it is load from main page, from menu and put into center content. however it looks like loading this page influences main page, because for example there is no css (that is still if I load subpage not from main_pages folder but from there where index is) and for example pictures are missing (which are declared in main page (index template) not in composition, how could it be?

Comment: You're welcome. As to your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/8368727#8368727 If you still stucks on that, please press `Ask Question` button. This is offtopic to the currently asked question.