# URLs Losing Application Name on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, url, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a Java application running on Tomcat 7. I want my application to have it's name in the URL. For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp
```

I build the WAR, deploy, and the application is accessed correctly. However, all of my `<a>` and `<form>` tags don't add the application name to the URLs. That is, doing something like:

```
<a href="/myPage">Click Me</a>
```

does not work. The link ends up like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myPage
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/myPage
```

Is there any way to configure Tomcat to add the application name onto links, etc? As mentioned, I don't want strip the application name off of the URL (i.e. making it the root). I know there are some work arounds (like manually adding the context path onto the URL, using `<c:url>`, etc. But I am wondering if Tomcat can be told to do this. I figure this is the place to ask, since the request isn't getting to my application. If it matters, I am using Spring MVC and Maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I know there are some work arounds (like manually adding the context path onto the URL, using `<c:url>`, etc.*

Those are not workarounds. Those are solutions. You just made a mistake of always assuming that the webapp runs on the domain root. Easiest solution -imo- is using the HTML `<base>`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735).

> *But I am wondering if Tomcat can be told to do this. I figure this is the place to ask, since the request isn't getting to my application.*

No. It's not servletcontainer's responsibility. Neither `JspServlet` nor `DefaultServlet` do this. It's the webapp's own responsibility (and the serveradmin's as far as applicable).

Comment: Okay. Looks like there isn't a way around. I guess I'll stick with the <c:url> tags (<base> has been acting weird for me). Thanks for the help.