# How to abstract Tomcat URL's for deployment?

Tags: svn, url, web-applications, tomcat, deployment

We have a web app running locally, so in many jsp's I have references to something like http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.html. We now want to create a deployment, but it seems inconvenient to go through many files of different languages (html, jsp, xml, etc.) and manually change the localhost URL's to the actual deployment URL - say 192.168.0.4:8080/MyApp/index.html.

What do people do here? Ideally I'd like the option of using both URL's so that I can maintain a local version of the webapp to run on my machine, and also have a deployed machine running on my network. One idea was to use a branch/tag in SVN as the deployment and change the URL's only in that branch. This may work for dev + deploy servers, but is there a more general way to abstract URL's used in a webapp?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/some/path/index.html
```

BalusC linked to another post that suggested this, but didn't have it in his answer, so I'm adding my own.

Comment: That wasn't what you were asking in the concrete question.

Comment: It isn't? Sorry, I'm happy to give you credit (I +1'd), but I think this is exactly what I was asking? Using ${pageContext.request.contextPath} abstracts the context...

Answer (score 1):

Don't hardcode the domainname nor the contextpath.

Resolve them dynamically. This information can be obtained from `HttpServletRequest`. E.g.

```
String base = request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI().substring(1), request.getContextPath());
// ...
```

Use it like follows

```xml
<a href="${base}/index.html">
```

Or use the HTML `<base>` tag. See also [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735) for some hints.

Comment: Great, thanks. What would you recommend I do in Java code that's in a separate server application (not Tomcat) that needs the same URL? Environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

It should generally be unnecessary to reference the full URL (including the protocol, host, port, and even the context root) within a web application when you are linking to another resource within the same application. Rather, you should be able to use relative URLs. For example, rather than referencing "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.html", you should be able to reference "index.html."