# how to handle 400,404,500,501 etc in spring?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee

How to handle 400,404,500,501 etc in a `BaseController` which can be extend by all child controllers in spring.

I need an example on this.

Comment: Handle or return in response?

Answer (score 1):

This is independent of spring, you can define it in the web.xml, have a look at [How to specify the default error page in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml-in-servlet)