# Configure view not found exception to show a 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, tomcat6

In our server we have a generic servlet mapping

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The problem is that not every *.do url is configured in the controllers, so calling a url ending with *.do that does not exists yields a 500 error while the same unexisting url not ending with *.do returns a proper 404

So I want to do is configure DispatcherServlet to return 404 on that cases or at least catch all those exceptions and return a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Add the above method inside your controller class. Every exception that will be thrown, even the RuntimeExceptions, they will be caught from this method.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GuestNavController.class).error(ex);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = initializeModelAndView("guest/error500");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

It is obvious that if you change the @ExceptionHandler exception parameter and the method argument (they have to be the same) you will be able to catch a specific exception.

In case you have more than one controller classes you should create a controller advice. You can add the above class in your source code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionManager {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionManager.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError404(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("ERROR 404: " + ex.getMessage());

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("guest/error404");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

You could add more than one methods inside this class. This methods will catch every exception that is thrown.
**Be carefull** in case you have included both the above solutions. If an exception is thrown in a controller that includes a method with an @ExceptionHandler annotation, the exception will be caught only by this method and not from the external class. The external class (solution 2) will catch an exception that is not caught by the internal method (solution 1).

Answer (score 0):

Beyond configuring an `<error-page/>` element in your deployment descriptor to specifically catch `404` errors or you don't have any other option. If you were using a full web application container, like glassfish, you have the option of overriding the `404` page at the container level also. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066536/1530938) for your options as per configurations (there is a new option with servlet 3.0)

Note that there is not such thing as a `ViewNotFoundException` in the JavaEE stack (I checked to be absolutely sure) because the container jumps in and takes control at the first hint that something may be fundamentally wrong with it's ability to serve a requested resource

The `4XX` series status codes are generally out of your control as a developer because they describe error conditions that you most likely cannot handle (`401-forbidden`, `404-Not found` etc) or shouldn't handle, kinda like java's runtime exceptions.