# during server exception redirect to another page in jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat

hi i am new to jsp(apache-tomcat) and i am doing a small project in jsp in that 
during catch exception i want to redirect some page in jsp and i worte the code like this

```
try
{
 //some code..
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("error==>"+e);
response.sendRedirect("Servererror.html");
}
```

during error or exception i can see the error by using System.out.println()
but the page is not redirecting

is there any problem in my code or am i doing anything wrong...please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a good practice that executing the code in catch block.

How ever if you want to show an error page for user,you can specify that in `web.xml`

```
 <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

If you want to show error pages by error codes (e.g 404,500 etc..or for custom exception handling) please [refer this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+Create+Custom+Error+Pages) .

And a  mini tutorial on this by [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml-in-servlet)

**EDIT:**

You need not to do anything with code now.You can simply write

```
try
{
 //some code..
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("error==>"+e);//better to write e.printStacktrace() here.
}
```

When error occurs the error page automatically shows in browser.

Comment: for this can i use throwable in catch block