# Error page configuration in web.xml not working

Tags: java, web, web.xml

I have the following configuration in my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>tycoon-sa</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>br.com.caelum.vraptor.encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <error-page>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>vraptor</filter-name>
        <filter-class>br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>vraptor</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My goal is to redirect the user to the main page in case of exceptions or error codes (404, 500, etc). But it's not working. I've tried to access an invalid URL and I was not redirected. The application throws a NullPointerException. Here's the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception  
java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:321)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.resource.DefaultResourceNotFoundHandler.couldntFind(DefaultResourceNotFoundHandler.java:41)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ResourceLookupInterceptor.intercept(ResourceLookupInterceptor.java:71)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.EnhancedRequestExecution.execute(EnhancedRequestExecution.java:44)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor$1.insideRequest(VRaptor.java:91)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.SpringProvider.provideForRequest(SpringProvider.java:58)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:88)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:456)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:327)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:193)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)  
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  

Abr 02, 2013 11:04:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom  
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/]  
java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:321)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.resource.DefaultResourceNotFoundHandler.couldntFind(DefaultResourceNotFoundHandler.java:41)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ResourceLookupInterceptor.intercept(ResourceLookupInterceptor.java:71)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.EnhancedRequestExecution.execute(EnhancedRequestExecution.java:44)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor$1.insideRequest(VRaptor.java:91)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.SpringProvider.provideForRequest(SpringProvider.java:58)  
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:88)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:456)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:327)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:193)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)  
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any clues?

Comment: One more info: I need to call a servlet because my error page has a pre processment.

Answer (score 1):

this is the way to configure a default error page for all the errors

```
<error-page>
<location>/whateverpage.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Remember this will only work if you are using **Servlet 3.0**. if you are still using Servlet 2.5 then you will have to specify each and every error code.

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/notfound.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
<error-code>403</error-code>
<location>/general-error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: So I can't define a route inside "location" tag to be treated by a Servlet?

Comment: i think you should be able to call a servlet using location

Comment: give your complete web.xml

Comment: where is the servlet you want to redirect to?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to say that I'm using a framework that handles this. You just simply configure a method annotation and it makes the servlet mapping. The framework is VRaptor. It's pretty simple to use :)

Comment: The browser shows a 404 report and the application throws a NullPointerException. I added the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 0):

error-page can not rediect invalid url .If you want to do that you can use apache server and write following

```
RewriteEngine on    
Redirect /--xyz-75/ http://www.domain.com.au/
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand why it's an invalid url.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the error code in your error page tag 
        
           404
           /ErrorPage.jsp

Comment: I'm not using error code tag. You don't need this tag on Servlet 3.0 if you want to catch any error code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml-in-servlet