# Handle HTTP status 500

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, exception, servlets

In my JSP page I use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#birthDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
$("#update").click(function (e) {
    var res = true;
    var alertMsg = "";
    $(".required").each(function (index) {
        if (this.value == null || this.value.length == 0) {
            alertMsg += this.name + " can't be empty! \n";
            res = false;
        }
    });

    if (res) {
        var response = $("#updateForm").submit();
        Window.location.reload();
    } else {
        alert(alertMsg);
    }
})
```

But, requested resource is not available, and I get this exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access remote service at [http://some.resource.com]; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current event not START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT
    com.dn.eb.controller.UpdateAccountServlet.throwException(UpdateAccountServlet.java:140)
    com.dn.eb.controller.UpdateAccountServlet.doPost(UpdateAccountServlet.java:122)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access remote service at [http://some.resource.com]; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current event not START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT
    org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:510)
    org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:487)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy98.updateAccountRecord(Unknown Source)
    com.dn.eb.controller.UpdateAccountServlet.doPost(UpdateAccountServlet.java:117)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

How can handle this exception, so that on my page displays the error message?

Comment: You want to show some error page with user friendly text instead of this exception?

Comment: If you want to display custom error page, this will be useful to you: [How to specify the default error page in web.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml-in-servlet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the error page in the web.xml :

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Now any `Throwable` thrown by the app will invoke the *error.jsp*.Or this way :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

All 500 errors will invoke *error.jsp*.

*error.jsp* is an error page which can be used to display error messages , declare the page directive in *error.jsp*:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true"%>
```

This gives your JSP an handle to the implicit `exception` object.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the actual response from your remote side. Most probably you'll see some boilerplate HTML saying your resource wasn't found, you are not authorized, or something similar instead of the actual WS response. This can happen when the WS server is hidden behind an Apache front end, which is misconfigured to assume you are a browser.