# how can i return response status 405 with empty entity?

Tags: java, rest, entity, jax-rs, http-status-code-405

How can i return response status 405 with empty entity in java REST?

```
@POST
@Path("/path")
public Response createNullEntity() {
    return Response.created(null).status(405).entity(null).build();
}
```

It returns status code 405, but the entity is not null, it is the http page for the error 405.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return an error status, Jersey delegates the response to your container's error processing via [`sendError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29). When `sendError` is called, the container will serve up an error page. This process is outlined in the [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) §10.9 Error Handling.

I suspect what you are seeing is your container's default error page for a 405 response. You could probably resolve your issue by [specifying a custom error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml) (which could be empty). Alternatively, Jersey won't use `sendError` if you provide an entity in your response. You could give it an empty string like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/path")
public Response createNullEntity() {
  return Response.status(405).entity("").build();
}
```

The above results in `Content-Length` of `0`

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I already tried this and i get the same entity (http page for the error 405) and content-lenght 980.

Comment: @junior are you using Jersey? What application server? I tested the above with Tomcat 7.0.39. You might also try a different content-type: `return Response.status(405).entity("").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();`

Comment: i am using jersey 1.17 and tomcat 7.0.12. I tried with different content type and same result. I tried with another status and it is working, i get the result i want.

Comment: @junior When you say you tried with another status, were you calling the same method (the POST at /path `createNullEntity`)? Maybe you're getting an _actual_ 405 error because you're trying to do something other than a POST on that path...have you verified that your method is actually being called? My example works for me, so other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: i tried on tomcat 7.0.39 and it works, on 6.0.35,7.0.12 and 7.0.22 versions it doesn't work. thank you for your help.