# How to specify the default error page in web.xml for 405?

Tags: java, web.xml

`<error-page>

   <error-code>405</error-code>

        <location>/Error405.html</location>

</error-page>`

whenever 405 occurs, i need to redirect this to Error405.html, will this work.?
If not can you specify how to get default error page for 405 error-code.??

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml