# what is the url pattern for http 404 on eclipse with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I would like to know what the URL pattern is for a HTTP 404 error page. When a user enters a wrong URL, I would like to know the URL pattern, so that I can customize the error page.

Comment: You should be able to add an entry into your `web.xml` file?

Comment: [You may find this answer helpful.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml)