# redirecting pages to one JSF index

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, glassfish

I have a jsf app which has an index page as default, configured on web.xml:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

So, if I navigate to the address **`http://myIp:8080/myContext/`** it redirects automatically to the address **`http://myIp:8080/myContext/faces/index.xhtml`**

I want to use this address in a way which allows the user to insert any text after the context address and the server automatically redirects to desired index, configured on welcome-file-list.

Some input examples that I want to redirect directly to my index page

**`http://myIp:8080/myContext/blahblahblah`**

**`http://myIp:8080/myContext/blahblahblah.jpg`**

**`http://myIp:8080/myContext/` (this is the only one working actually)**

Obs.: I'm using glassfish, if the web container matters

Comment: `http://myIp:8080/myContext/blahblahblah.jpg` or `http://myIp:8080/myContext/blahblahblah` could be valid paths for your web application, under what circumstances should you redirect them to the index page? That should trigger a 404 error per se. Unless you want to secure your application, then it should show the login view and once you're logged in try to redirect to the firstly requested resource.

Comment: May my 404 page be the index? This way I could redirect these invalid paths always to the index page

Comment: Usually popular sites have a pretty page where they show a 404 error. You could instead redirect to your index page, of course. Spanish BBC site, as an example, does it to a `categories` page: http://www.bbc.es/fsdafsd. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7066536/1199132) link to show different views depending on the error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by @xtreme-biker, I used the 404 error to trigger the index page.

This is the code I added to the web.xml 
Thus, any address I insert in the browser, it redirects me to the index page.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>faces/index.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```