# Java EE - more generic error code mapping

Tags: java, xml, error-handling, enterprise

I'm currently mapping error codes in `web.xml` and so far it looks like this:

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorHandler?code=404</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorHandler?code=500</location>
  </error-page>
```

Do I have to map every single error code manually or is there more automatic way? I'd like to have something like this:

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>*</error-code>
    <location>/errorHandler?code=*</location>
  </error-page>
```

Comment: Define generic error-page. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7066536/3315474).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible, according to the documentation of [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017571). It depends on whether you are using servlet 2.5 (not supported) or 3.0 (supported).

I would recommend you to use plain html for the error codes.
The reason behind this, is these pages will be shown when something is going very wrong. [Full list of status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Generic solution example: [moreinfo with onehippo](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/error-pages-and-error-handling/1.-handling-error-codes-and-exceptions-by-the-web.xml.html)

From security perspective it is not recommended to give information what went wrong in the application: https://blog.whitehatsec.com/error-handling-in-java-web-xml/

Comment: Thanks to your last link I found out I can use `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");` instead of passing error code value from `web.xml` and then remove `<error-code>` tag completely. Great answer.