# Dynamic error pages in Java Web App?

Tags: java, war, web.xml, custom-error-pages, dynamic-pages

### How do I generate error pages dynamically instead of serving static pages?  Or is this impossible?

I am working on my first Java Web App and I am trying to learn the intricacies of the web.xml configuration file. My understanding based on [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017571) is that error pages are configured by specifying a static file to be served for a given HTTP status code or Java exception. For example...

#### This would serve a page for [internal server errors](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1)

```
...
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errors/http/500.html</location>
</error-page>
...
```

#### This would serve a page for [servlet exceptions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletException.html)

```
...
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/java/servlet_exception.html</location>
</error-page>
...
```

#### This would [specify a default error page for everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml)

```
...
<error-page>
    <location>/errors/index.html</location>
</error-page>
...
```

### But how do I send this information to a script/class?

I want my error pages to be pretty standard. Maybe include a logo, the error code, and a brief message based on the error. I would like the status code or exception type to be passed as parameters to the script/class. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do not include data about Exceptions (or anything else that can identity the server/framework you're using) on any page.  This is a security risk which would provide key data to hackers about your system architecture, etc.

Comment: @AndrewS Thank you for the reminder but I have clearly stated that I am using a Java Web App, so isn't it a fair assumption that I would be using `javax.servlet`? I didn't feel like that would be giving away much.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to:

1. setup an error-page as a servlet or jsp (the "error handler")
2. within your error handler you will get several data, describing the error, as request attribute.
   Example:
   let's say you configure your web.xml with 2 directives to handle 404 status codes and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exceptions.

When you cause a 404, the error handler will see the following request attributes:

```
javax.servlet.forward.request_uri /testwebapp1/errordd 
javax.servlet.forward.context_path /testwebapp1 
javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path /errordd 
javax.servlet.forward.path_info /error 
javax.servlet.error.message /testwebapp1/errordd 
javax.servlet.error.status_code 404 
javax.servlet.error.servlet_name default 
javax.servlet.error.request_uri /testwebapp1/errordd
```

**javax.servlet.error.status_code** contains the http status code

If you cause an IllegalArgumentException, the request attributes will contain an attribute "javax.servlet.error.exception_type" with the raised exception.
More details about these constants  can be found here
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/constant-values.html

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. I will approve your answer as correct once I test it.