# Custom Error Page When Apache Tomcat7 is Restarting?

Tags: java, tomcat7, whm

Currently using custom error pages on the Java web application which is great. To cover all bases, when restarting Tomcat after pushing out an update, there is a very minor 30 second delay restarting the Tomcat service which shows the standard Apache 503 error message. It just looks horrible.

I've looked everywhere for where to find this file to customise. Any ideas? The server is running CentOS6 with Apache Tomcat 7 which has been installed via Easy Apache 3 on cPanel's WHM.

Comment: As Tomcat7 is getting restarted, The tomcat configs can not help  you in that case. you can have a proxy server set up, simply apache or nginx type servers. Which will redirect your requests to the tomcat7 and works as proxy if that is not available you can show error page, which can be handled by minor proxy settings in light weight servers.

Comment: Thanks for the info @HardikSheth The proxy server sounds like an interesting solution, probably a bit over kill for what I'm thinking at the moment. Where is the "503 Error" page coming from that is being served when tomcat is restarting? I would have thought it would be possible to customise this file on the server itself?

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml