# Setting up Custom html Page for different error messages in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

I would like to display a single(custom) web page when tomcat encounters different errors such as 403, 404, 405 etc. I have tried with the below solutions.

I have pasted my custom error.html in the prweb folder in webapps folder and pasted the below code in web.xml

```
<error-page>
<location>$Catalina_home/WEB-INF/webapps/prweb/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

**Output : Tomcat didn't launch my app and directly displayed 404 error page.**

I have pasted my custom error.html in the WEB-INF folder in webapps folder and pasted the below code in web.xml

```
<error-page>
<location>./error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

**Output : Tomcat didn't launch my app and directly displayed 404 error page.**

Can anyone please help me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use error-page with exception-type or error-code .

Also you can define an error page for all only with a specified Servlet version (3.0 I think).

please check this also

[How to specify the default error page in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml)

And you may have used an invalid page url! you can use "/WEB-INF/..." if you are not sure about it.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 8.5 which holds the servlet of v3.0. For suppose I've put my error.html file in tomcat-8.5/WEB-INF folder, can you please help me what exactly is the path I have to provide in <location> in web.xml?

Comment: Usually the IDE recommend you when you type /WEB-INF.

Comment: As I'm using notepad, there will not be such recommendations. In other posts, I have read that path has to be "$Catalina_home/WEB-INF/error.html" or as I've pasted the file in WEB-INF, path can be "./error.html" but both of them didn't work.Can anyone please provide the exact path that needs to be specified if my file is in WEB-INF folder(main folder not in webapps/appnfolder).

Comment: I think it's not too hard to find it. Generate the war file and browse it. You can see where is the error.html