# Tomcat returns 505 for request URI with spaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, error-handling, http-status-code-505

I'm using embedded Tomcat 9.0.13 in my springboot2 app sitting behind a nginx reverse proxy.

When I send a request with space, it returns 505. The request isn't even passed into the servlet so I am unable to add custom error handling in the application level.

How can I display a custom page for this 505 error? Also, is there a way to not treat this as a 505 and automatically encode the whitespaces?

eg URI:
"http://app/hello world"
"http://app/api?key=hello world"

Comment: 505 means `HTTP version not supported`. It's most probably not because of the whitespace. And yes - you can add custom error pages per error code - see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml

Comment: From where you are hitting the URL. If it is any browser, it will encode the space to %20 probably.

Answer (score 0):

try using character code for sapce in url param.