# Servlet link relative to application base

Tags: java, scala, servlets, scalate

I am writing a servlet (specifically with Scalatra).  In the servlet I have many links on a table of contents which is included with every page.  I want these links to be relative to the application base.  If I use links such as "/foo", everything works fine when the servlet is served from the root (localhost:8080/) but if I serve it from Jetty/Tomcat along with other servlets (localhost:8080/servlet) the link points outside of the servlet.

What is a good fix for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to prepend the link URL with a domain-relative path including the context path as obtained by [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29). I don't do Scala, so I can't give a Scala-targeted answer, but here's how you'd do it in JSP so that the picture is sound:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlet">link</a>
```

When the current context path is `/foo`, then the above will end up in HTML as

```
<a href="/foo/servlet">link</a>
```

Or if you're generating HTML programmatically using Java inside a servlet class (which is actually a poor practice, but that aside):

```
out.println("<a href=\"" + request.getContextPath() + "/servlet\">link</a>");
```

An alternative is to set the `<base>` tag in HTML so that all relative links are relative to it, see also this answer for more detail: [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp/3658735#3658735)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it put me on the right track.  Jade (scala HTML template engine) provides the variable `context` of type [ScalatraRenderContex](http://www.scalatra.org/2.0/api/org/scalatra/scalate/ScalatraRenderContext.html).  It can be used as `#{context.contextPath}`.