# urlrewrite using Servlet filter

Tags: java, servlets, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

I'm trying to write a simple urlrewriter using Servlet's filter (`javax.servlet.Filter`). The filter inspects all requests and reroutes to servlet (or JSP) depending on the URL.

Example: http://server/app/person/Roscoe would be translated to http://server/app/person.jsp?name=Roscoe

My `Filter`'s `doFilter` inspects the request, and if the pattern matches, creates a new `HttpServletRequest` and passes it to `chain.doFilter`. The new `HttpServletRequest` extends `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper` and overrides the parameters, URI, URL, query string, and servlet path to look like the new JSP (`/person.jsp?name=Roscoe`). I thought that by passing the new request to `chain.doFilter` it would redirect to the JSP. This works, sort of, except that the contents of `person.jsp` are returned to the browser. `person.jsp` never executes the contents are returned as plain text (`Content-Type: text/plain`).

My `web.xml` has the filter and filter-mapping:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is this the correct was to use a Servlet filter to rewrite the request?

I am aware of existing urlrewriters (such as [Tuckey](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)) but would still like to write my own, mainly to learn and for better control.

**Follow-up**: I've also tried redirecting instead of `chain.doFilter` by doing (where `req` is the wrapped request):

```
config.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/person.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

This works better, but my CSS file (`styles.css`) is still relative to original URL http://server/app/person/styles.css, whereas it should be http://server/app/styles.css

**Follow-up 2**: The path issue is covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316).

Comment: Did you check http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/?

Comment: "I am aware of existing urlrewriters (such as Tuckey) but would still like to write my own, mainly to learn and for better control."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrapping the request and changing its state isn't sufficient. You'll need to forward/redirect to the appropriate resource. Filters and servlets are mapped to a URL pattern. The chain you're executing in was built based on the pattern of the incoming request's URL. Changing the URL in the request and passing it to the next item in the chain isn't going to rebuild the chain to account for the new URL. That's what a forward/redirect is for.